# How to add a row to group data in a jQuery DataTable PDF export?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, export-to-pdf

I am using jQuery DataTables and would like to add a row in between to group data in a PDF export. I understand that grouping is not supported in PDF exports, so I am looking for a way to manually add a row to achieve this. Is there a way to do this by modifying the

```
doc.content[1].table.body
```

property or through some other means? Any help would be appreciated.

I tried a lot of forums from the official DataTable website but found no specific help. I have a DataTable with grouping that adds a subtotal amount in the table, but it is not being rendered in the pdf export.